# Ncomputing M300 / Ubuntu 12.04 issues with browsers

Tags: virtual-terminal

Everything works fine with 6 terminals using Ncomputing M300 clients with an I3 host (8 GB and 2 TB) running Vspacr L.3.2.2.27. But when I use Firefox, Opera or Thunderbird the systems logs off. (**Splash Screen ---  Ncomputing  Press any key to start)**. I can log in again and use the other applications except the above web based applications.